# how to create matrix in PHP with data from mysql (2)?

Tags: php, mysql

I have this code:

```
function    random()  
{  
 include('config/koneksi.php');  
  $result = mysql_query("select * from temp_hasil");  
  $n =mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM temp_hasil"));

for ($i = 1; $i <= $n; $i++)
{

 for ($j = 1; $j <= $n; $j++)    
    {

           $rows = mysql_fetch_array($result);


        $this->table[$i][$j] = $i == $j ? INF :  $rows['id'];


    }
}
}

function    __toString()  
{  
    $str = '<table class="table table-bordered" id="tableInput"> <tbody>';  
$str .= '<tr><td></td>';  
foreach ($this->table as $rowName => $row)  
{  
    $str .= "<td>$rowName</td>";  
}  
$str .= '</tr>';  
foreach ($this->table as $rowName => $row)  
{  
    $str .= "<tr><td>$rowName</td>";  
    foreach ($row as $columnName => $value)  
    {  
        $str .= "<td>";  
        $str .=  
            '<input class="form-control" type="text" value="' . $value . '" name="table[' . $rowName . '][' .
            $columnName . ']" requied' . ($columnName == $rowName ? ' disabled' : '') . '>';
        $str .= "</td>";
    }
    $str .= '</tr>';
}
$str .= '</tbody></table>';
return $str;
}

}
$str .= '</tr>';  
foreach ($this->table as $rowName => $row)  
{  
    $str .= "<tr><td>$rowName</td>";  
    foreach ($row as $columnName => $value)  
    {    
        $str .= "<td>";  
        $str .=  
            '<input class="form-control" type="text" value="' . $value . '" name="table[' . $rowName . '][' .
            $columnName . ']" requied' . ($columnName == $rowName ? ' disabled' : '') . '>';
        $str .= "</td>";    
    }      
    $str .= '</tr>';    
}  
$str .= '</tbody></table>';    
return $str;    
}`
```

and I have table "temp_hasil" such as:

```
  id_temp  | id |          
  1        |  8 |  
  2        |  5 |    
  3        |  7 |
```

If I run this code, it result :

```
      1     2    3 
 1  | INF  |  5 |  7 |
 2  |      | INF|    |
 3  |      |    | INF|
```

But I want end result such as:

```
      1     2    3 
 1  | INF  |  5 |  7 |
 2  |  8   | INF|  7 |
 3  |  8   |  5 | INF|
```

How do I code it in php? Is there anything wrong code? Thanks,... :)

Comment: From your result, It looks your loop work for first time correctly, second time only for 2nd column and 3rd time form only 3 rd column

Comment: Problem in for loop definatly.Can you show your array format by using echo "<pre/>";print_r($n)? it will help us.

Comment: if I write command echo $rows; end result Notice: Array to string conversion Array. I am sorry I still do not understand. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is - You can only fetch complete results once and can't get the first record in second loop. So instead, store the results in an array and use the array to create matrix.

This should work. Try this.

```
function random()  
{  
 include('config/koneksi.php');  
 $result = mysql_query("select * from temp_hasil");  
 $n =mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM temp_hasil"));

 $r=array();
 for ($a = 1; $a <= $n; $a++)    
 {
     $rows = mysql_fetch_array($result);
     $r[]=$rows['id'];
 }
 for ($i = 1; $i <= $n; $i++)
 {
    for ($j = 1; $j <= $n; $j++)    
    {
        $this->table[$i][$j] = $i == $j ? INF :  $r[$j-1];
    }
 }
}
```

Simply, you can use a `while` loop and store to array and then use array `sizeof($r)` or `count($r)` in `for` loop. Which ever you prefer.

```
function random()  
{  
 include('config/koneksi.php');  
 $result = mysql_query("select * from temp_hasil");

 $r=array();
 while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
     $r[]=$rows['id'];
 }
 for ($i = 1; $i <= sizeof($r); $i++)
 {
    for ($j = 1; $j <= sizeof($r); $j++)    
    {
        $this->table[$i][$j] = $i == $j ? INF :  $r[$j-1];
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: I've tried the code above to run, but result it : Notice: Undefined offset: 4 in C:\xampp\htdoc\code.php. And the first record can't get. for second record and third record display.

Comment: I've tried it, but the result is the same. Please help me. The fisrt record not get.

Comment: I guess the problem in my code is with array reference. So I've updated it so as to refer it correctly using `$j-1` instead of `$j`. Please let me know if it still doesn't work.

Comment: Mr. Avinash can you help me again? I hope you can help me.

Comment: Sure, but this solution works right? Or you need help in another problem?

Comment: yes, this solution work right. Yes, I have another problem about BranchAndBound Agorithm.

Comment: Mr. Avinash .. I have problem again. I Have new question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29329040/how-create-dynamic-matrix-in-php